# How to adjustbox trim logo in preamble?

Tags: beamer, adjustbox, logos

I have an official logo, which has white background and much margins around. 
So the logo does not look good without trimming at the top-left corner of Berkley theme in Beamer. 
Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usetheme{Berkeley} 
\logo{
% llx lly urx ury
\adjustbox{trim=0.2\width{} 0.1\height{} 0.2\width{} 0.1\height{}, clip, height=1.2\textheight{}}{
\includegraphics[height=1cm]{logo.png}
}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{titlepage}
Leo Leopold Hertz. 
\end{titlepage}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Fig. 1 Logo example, 
Fig. 2 Output of the code

[image]
[image]

### Testing samcarter's answer with random image

I try to auto-adjust width and height of the image but I cannot get it to work

```
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/215317/13173
\includegraphics[trim=5.3cm 0.2cm 5cm 1.2cm,clip, width=\beamer@sidebarwidth,height=\beamer@headheight]{logo.p‌​ng}
```

### Final proposal which works

```
\includegraphics[trim=5.3cm 0.2cm 5cm 1.2cm,clip, height=\headheight, width=\headheight]{logo.p‌​ng}
```

OS: Debian 8.5
TeXLive: 2016

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: If you want trim/clip included graphics (as your logo), use the `trim` and `clip` options of `\includegraphics`. The `adjustbox` package provides options to clip or trim LaTeX mateial.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 Here are [examples](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/289800/why-trim-then-clip-in-includegraphics).

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 Did you try to use `trim` and `clip` options of `\includegraphics`? If so, what is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I still have no idea, what your intended output should look like, so this is just a guess:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Berkeley} 

\logo{%
    \includegraphics[trim=5.3cm 0.2cm 5cm 1.2cm, clip, height=\headheight]{logo.png}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{titlepage}
Leo Leopold Hertz. 
\end{titlepage}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 Why would you want that?

Comment: Yes, this works `height=\headheight, width=\headheight`.